# How to order by heading and then the description

Tags: codeigniter

I have a table with heading and description when user searches the blog it should list first all the heading and then the description currently it is ordering by date created. And search should be case insenstive

```
  $SQL = "(SELECT * FROM {$this->blogs} WHERE Lower(heading) LIKE '%" .strtolower($query) . "%' ) 
        UNION
        (SELECT * FROM {$this->blogs} WHERE  Lower(description) LIKE '%" . strtolower($query) ."%')";
$run = $this->db->query( $SQL );
```

**Query1**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_wonderblogs WHERE LOWER(heading) LIKE '%indian army amfc%' ) UNION (SELECT * FROM tbl_wonderblogs WHERE LOWER(description) LIKE '%indian army amfc%'
```

**Query2**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_wonderblogs WHERE LOWER(heading) LIKE '%indian army afmc%' ) UNION (SELECT * FROM tbl_wonderblogs WHERE LOWER(description) LIKE '%indian army afmc%'
```

What is difference between query1 and query2 in which query 1 yeild results and query 2 does not yeild any results

Answer (score 0):

The results are sorted by date created because of this code

```
$this->db->order_by('createdon DESC');
```

It asks that output is sorted by the contents of the `createdon` field in descending order.

I think you will find the following will make the output sort the way you want.

```
$this->db->order_by('description DESC, heading DESC');
```

There are a couple of different ways to use the `order_by()` method as shown in [the documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results). The following will produce the same result as the previous code.

```
$this->db->order_by('description' 'DESC');
$this->db->order_by('heading', 'DESC');
```